# How to get children of the ListView in xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

```
<ListView x:Name="ListNewsLetter"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"  SeparatorVisibility="Default" VerticalOptions="Fill" ItemTapped="ListNewsLetter_ItemTapped" HasUnevenRows="True">
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                  <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="5">
                    <StackLayout Padding="1" BackgroundColor="#f15a23" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                      <StackLayout x:Name="stkNewsLetter" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="#f15a23" Orientation="Horizontal" HeightRequest="30" Padding="6,0,6,0">
                        <Label x:Name="lblName" Text="{Binding NewsHeadline}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" TextColor="White" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Small"/>
                        <Image x:Name="imgPlus_Minus" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" Source="ico_down_arrow2_right.png" HorizontalOptions="End" ClassId="{Binding TapId}">
                          <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="img_Tapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                          </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Image>
                      </StackLayout>
                      <StackLayout x:Name="stkNewsLetterDetail" Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="#ffffff" IsVisible="true" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="6,0,6,0">
                        <Label x:Name="lblDate" Text="{Binding NewsDate}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="#585858" FontSize="Small"/>
                        <Label x:Name="lblDetail" Text="{Binding NewsDetails}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="#585858" FontSize="Small"/>
                      </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                  </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell.View>
              </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

As you see in code ListView having main two child named "stkNewsLetter" and "stkNewLetterDetail". First Stack having Image and I want to change visibility of second stack on Image tap event.

***In windows phone It will possible to get UI elements of List view but In xamarin.forms how it is possible?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should bind to the Visability property on the stackLayout in the same way you are binding the Text. If the stackLayout doesn't have a visibility property you may need to wrap it within another control that does.

The click should change a visibility property in you viewmodel which will get picked up by the binding mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

For those who came here to get the child elements through Name like me,here is the solution:

```
var selectedItem = //any item selected within listview through OnItemTapped
StackLayout child1 = selectedItem.FindByName<StackLayout>("stkNewsLetter");
```

Comment: I didn't get the nested item of a listview like this.

Comment: Okay, my mistake. Instead of ListNewsLetter, you need to write the item which is selected